# How can I assue Defer loading javascript on local

Tags: javascript

I am implementing JS blocking in my web application and referring [this](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-loading-javascript.html) document.
here is the code:

```
  function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "Myfile.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
    else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
```

Now, after implementing this code how can I assure that my JS is loading after page load on local project.

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: What code? I don't see

Comment: Code please. This is not a site for  Suggestion as you find in Forums. Sorry!

Comment: any recent browsers developer tools should be able to show you exactly what you need

Comment: I have installed page speed insights in chrome browser. But how can I assure that it loads after page load

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome > Developer Tools > Network tab and look for the DomContentLoaded event (blue line in picture below)

[image]